# how to embed HTML in C code In Code::block IDE?

Tags: html, c, ide

there is an option of (Run Html and Run CHM) Doxyblocks in Code::Blocks IDE, Inorder to run a Html code we need to integrate it first somewhere?? MY question where to integrate HTML code?

Comment: HTML is markup, there's no code in there... nothing to run... do you mean Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

As per info Doxyblocks website it creates a documentation, insert comment blocks and run HTML or CHM documents (from your source code). So after you **created** the documentation in **different formats** *(**note:** you have to set it in doxyblock's prefences)* like Html and CHM, then only you are  able to run.
Hope this answers your question.

Please do visit the website [DoxyBlocks Plugin](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/DoxyBlocks_plugin) for more information.